# How to check for existence of file without generating an exception?

Tags: android

I am checking to see if a file exists on the device as follows:

```
boolean fileExists = new File(fullPathName).isFile();
```

It works fine, but logcat gives me two errors if the file isn't there:

```
BitmapFactory | Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <fullPathName> ...
```

and

```
JHEAD | can't open <fullPathName> ...
```

How can I check for file existence without generating an exception?

Comment: where does your file exist. is it on the sdcard. can you post how you get the fullPathName?

Comment: The full path name is correct.  I've been using it for a long time to obtain photos from the device, and write them to an ImageView within a ListView.  All I'm doing now is adding an indeterminate progress bar in case I need to get it from the network.  (If file doesn't exist locally: show prog bar, get photo from the network, hide prog bar, and show photo.  If file exists locally: just show it.  All that logic works fine, so I know the file path is OK.)

Comment: have you added permisssion in manifest file?

Comment: Yes, the app already reads and writes local files.  Specifically, I have: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
File f= new File(fullPathName);
if(f.exists())
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was my first solution.  It gives the same errors.

Comment: @gcl1 Perform operation on it, if it satisfy the above condition..i.e if file exist

Comment: @gcl1: "It gives the same errors" -- your error comes from `BitmapFactory`, according to what you have pasted in your question. `BitmapFactory` is not `File`. Presumably, you have some other bug in your code, related to the use of `BitmapFactory`. Since you did not include any `BitmapFactory`-related code, we cannot help you further. Consider editing your question to provide **all of the code** and **all of the stack trace** related to your error.

Comment: @CommonsWare: you got it.  I added check for file existence before decoding.  That cleared the BitmapFactory error, and it now works without errors on one of my test devices.  But I still get the "JHEAD | can't open ..." error on another device.  Any clues on JHEAD?

Comment: @gcl1: Since you have not edited your question to supply all of the relevant information (per my last comment), I cannot help you further.

Comment: @Commonsware: I found it.  The problem was in a different section of code relating to reading Exif data (to ensure proper orientation of photos).  My bad for posting a red herring of a question.  But thanks for your gentle reminder to read my own error messages.  And I'm still wondering what JHEAD is ....

Comment: @CommonsWare a legend in android. Commented on my answer..always inspired by the people like you..Thank you sir for your support.